# Change the depletion width in the presence of light in a photodiode

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In my simulations, in the presence of light, the depletion width of the layer decreases.
Can light change the depletion width of the photodiode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a diode the depletion layer thickness is dependent on the applied voltage. Rather than give all the details here let me [refer you to the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region#Determining_the_Depletion_Layer_Width) as this gives a detailed description of the calculation.

When you illuminate a photodiode a potential difference will be generated and this will affect the depletion layer thickness as described in the Wikipedia article. Exactly how the depletion layer is affected will depend on what circuit the diode is in i.e. whether it is open circuit or has a load attached.

Comment: And in the extreme, you can generate so many carriers that the doping levels at the junction are totally irrelevant.